# vba left function doesnt work as planned

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get partial of the Account Code using left function but it seemed like it doesn't work the way I want to. All of my data are in worksheet named Codes. I have Account Name in Column B & Account Code in Column C, and I want to populate the parent code in column A.

Now the code works except when the codes are 0001-xx-xx, it populates in Column A as 1 not 0001. Is there a way to fix it so it shows 0001 or 0022 and such? When I typed out the formula in excel, it will show 0002 or 0022. So I would like to achieve this using vba.

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
With Sheets("Codes")
lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
      With .Range("A5:A" & lLastRow)
         .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[2],4)"
         .Value = .Value
      End With
End With
```

Comment: Wrap it in a text call:  `=TEXT(LEFT(RC[2],4), "0000")`

Comment: when i replaced my codes with yours, it has syntax error. I tried using recording macros, it also telling me to use the same formula as above, .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[2],4)"

Comment: Sorry, you need to double up the quotes `=TEXT(LEFT(RC[2],4), ""0000"")`

Comment: FWIW You're calling Excel's `LEFT` worksheet function, not VBA's `Left` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stick with your approach, you can add an apostrophe to the formula so that it will format the numbers as text and not remove the leading zeros:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long

With Sheets("Codes")
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A5:A" & lLastRow)
       .FormulaR1C1 = "= ""'"" &LEFT(RC[2],4)"
       .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Although the apostrophe won't be visible in the cell, it will still be there.  If that causes problems, then you can use this approach:

```
Sub foo()

    Dim lLastRow    As Long
    Dim arrCodes()  As Variant
    Dim rng         As Range
    Dim i           As Integer

    With Sheets("Codes")
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("C5:C" & lLastRow)
        arrCodes = rng
        arrCodes = Application.Transpose(arrCodes)

        For i = LBound(arrCodes) To UBound(arrCodes)
            arrCodes(i) = Left(arrCodes(i), 4)
        Next i

        Set rng = .Range("A5")
        Set rng = rng.Resize(UBound(arrCodes), 1)
        rng.NumberFormat = "@"
        rng.Value = Application.Transpose(arrCodes)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format to text:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
With Sheets("Codes")
lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
      With .Range("A5:A" & lLastRow)
         .NumberFormat = "@"
         .FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[2],4)"
         .Value = .Value
      End With
End With
```